# Who's responsible for disposing HttpPostedFile.InputStream - and when?

Tags: asp.net

When you receive an uploaded file in ASP.NET, you generally do so via an `HttpPostedFile` object.  The received data is made available via `HttpPostedFile.InputStream`.  This is a property, which would lead me to believe I don't need to dispose it myself, however the documentation never mentions who *is* responsible for disposing the stream, and if it's done by the ASP.NET framework, *when* it does so (say, can I save the stream in the session, should I wish to?).

Now, I don't receive that many files, and I've not run into problems for not disposing this particular stream, but for cleanliness - does anyone know what the design contract here is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my experience working with it I would say that it is released as soon as the request processing is complete.  An example is if I were to throw a ball into the air.  If I don't catch it and it hits the ground...it is disposed of.  If I catch it and do something with it...and then drop it is disposed of.  It doesn't hang around for you to play with in the next request!

Addressing the issue of storing it in the session I would say NOOOOOO!  If you need it to be around for a while write it to the file system.  When you need it again reconstitute it as a stream and play with it.  Storing a file stream in the session (as a byte array perhaps?) sounds like a huge waste of your session (memory) resources.

Comment: Admittedly, storing the thing in the session sounds like a bad idea; I was merely trying to find an example where it would be relevant to know the exact lifetime of the stream.

Perhaps a better example would be starting a background worker to process and save the image and continueing with the webrequest in the foreground - the web request may complete before the worker, so you'd need to know when the stream precisely becomes invalid.  In any case, I suppose you're right - though I'd have appreciated better docs from microsoft on this one (as on so many IDisposable issues).

Comment: Even if you want to hand it off to a background process...which is great to do...I would still save the file to the file system and pass a reference to the file to your background thread rather than passing the instance of the stream.

Comment: Given that the InputStream is closed beyond my control, I'll certainly do something like that - but in general, to avoid bottlenecks, I prefer avoiding temporary disk access - and a temporary albeit large byte array isn't a problem.  Thanks for the info, anyhow!

Comment: Per this documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx 

"Server resources that are allocated to buffer the uploaded file will be destroyed when the request ends."

But I'm still tempted to call a Dispose() on it as soon as I save the uploaded file, instead of waiting to the end of the request process.  Does anyone think this is a good or bad idea?

Comment: @Kon: just try it.  If it works - i.e. doesn't crash - then it can't harm to release the resources a bit earlier, even though it probably doesn't really matter (performance wise) since requests are processed so quickly anyhow.  Also, there's a small chance disposing it may break unrelated code such as (say) a Virus-scanning module if it's active *after* your code.  However, that sounds pretty far-fetched; I'd say it's probably fine to release the file earlier.

Comment: Well, nothing broke... so I guess I'll be disposing manually asap.